# Fluid simulation – change object type

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

**Question:** Given a fluid simulation, is it possible to change the '*Type*' of a given object, halfway through the simulation?

**Context:** Let's say I have three ice-cubes that are melting. At frame 1, the three are solid; at frame 10, the first one melts, and its liquid flows around the other two; at frame 20, the second melts, and its liquid mixes with the liquid of the first one, and flows around the last ice cube; and, at frame 30, the third melts as well, and we are left with only liquid.

**My attempt:** The naive, most natural solution would be to set the three cubes to be a '*Fluid - Effector*', and change their type into '*Fluid - Flow - Geometry*' at the corresponding frames, one by one. It appears that the type is immutable, so what is the second best way to accomplish this?

I thought of duplicating the cubes, and making one copy into an effector, and the other one into a flow. At the right frame, I would turn off the effector and turn on the flow. The former works fine: effectors can be turned off (with "*Use Effector*" button); but the latter does not: I don't seem to be able to figure out how to specify when the flow object is to begin pouring its content out. '*Geometry*' type doesn't seem to allow one to turn it on at a specific frame. (On the other hand, '*Inflow*' type does allow this, so perhaps one could turn it on for just a single frame, thus mimicking the behaviour of '*Geometry*'). So this approach doesn't seem to work off the bat, and even if it did, I feel there should be something better than duplicating all objects this way, and carefully orchestrating their behaviour frame by frame (especially considering I have many more than just three cubes, and they should all behave this way, at different points in time). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think you’ve hit upon the best way by duplicating the objects and controlling the Inflow for just a single frame. This might seem a bit “clunky” but I’d say it’s probably the simplest way of achieving it.

Comment: @RichSedman Oh, that's... disappointing? Anyway, thank you for your input!

Comment: Someone else might be able to prove me wrong here. The physics engines are all being re-developed for ‘everything nodes’ to be node based - so that might help too, when it comes around. Check out the daily experimental builds. I like your inventive user name.